# Production build of electron still has toggle developer tools in menu

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am trying to build a production build of electron for mac, it still has default menu items,
File, Edit, View, Window, Help.
And the worst thing is Toggle Developer Tools is still there.
I have set the menu to null still the same problem in a different way, now the developer tools option is visible but it's greyed out.

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, shell, Menu } = require("electron");
Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);
```

Electron version : 9.3.2

[image]

Is there a way to disable these default options?? I am using electron builder.

Package.json mac config

```json
"mac": {
      "publish": [
        {
          "provider": "spaces",
          "name": "releases",
          "region": "sfo2",
          "channel": "latest",
          "path": "/mac",
          "acl": "public-read"
        }
      ],
      "category": "public.app-category.developer-tools",
      "icon": "build-resources/app.iconset",
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "dmg",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "zip",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "darkModeSupport": false,
      "type": "distribution"
    },
```